# Jinja templating engine filters

Tags: python, django, jinja2

The jinja filter `replace` isn't working... not even recognized as a jinja valid filter. I am using django.. what should I do.

```
{{ post.article | safe | replace("&lt;script", "lt;") }}
```

what am I missing

error come up:

> template syntax error Invalid filter: 'replace'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here. First, syntax: it was corrected by @t0bi. Second: filter `safe` will replace symbol `<`, so your replace will not find substring `"<script"`. Try this:

```
{{ post.article | replace:"<script","lt;" | safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{% with article=post.article|safe %}
{{article|replace:"<script", "It;"}}
{% endwith %}
```